# Materializecss Setting an Initial Value

Tags: autocomplete, materialize

I am using Materializecss 0.100.2
I am using an autocomplete in my form.
I have no issues with getting the autocomplete to work if data is entered in via the user.
However I want the form to retain the data if there is an error when submitting the form.
I am unsure how to set the value for the autocomplete field.

Can someone direct me to the best way to do this.
TIA.